# There has been an error processing your request, Error log record number

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I installed Magento, logged in admin panel. But if I press on any link to open let say CMS pages or users configuration, I get error like this:

> There has been an error processing your request
>       Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 673618173351

That error log record number looks like a link, but pressing it nothing happens. I tried to look for some log file in magento files, but didn't find any.

So actually I can only connect to admin panel, but can't do anything here.

What could be wrong? I installed the newest Magento version (magento-1.7.0.2). Default frontend opens and works.

P.S.

.If any additional information is needed, just say it

Update:

So in logs every error is the same (just accessed resource is different).

> a:5:{i:0;s:71:"Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually";i:1;s:4546:"#0 /home/geniusinsi/domains/example.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend.php(197): Zend_Cache::throwException('Could not deter...')

As I understand I need to specify cash directory somewhere?

Comment: pls start or restart your apache and MySql in xaamp or WAMP.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Go to `magento/var/report` and open the file with the Error log record number name i.e `673618173351` in your case. In that file you can find the complete description of the error.

For log files like `system.log` and `exception.log`, go to `magento/var/log/`.

Comment: 1) Open Magento root directory and create tmp folder.

2) Set directory permissions to 777 or 755

2) Open “lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php“, and locate the following code


protected $_options = array(
‘cache_dir’ => null,
replace with

protected $_options = array(
‘cache_dir’ => ‘tmp’,

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. The question would be is something went wrong for not creating default tmp folder? Or it should be like that?

Comment: may be permission issue or magento version issue. You can magento log enable. go to System-> Configuration->ADVANCED->Developer->Log Settings , Enabled set as yes and give permission   755 for var/log/ folder. then its writes every logs to two file. Cheers

Comment: there's no report folder in var

Answer (score 6):

You can see the error information from:

> Magento/var/report

Most of the time it is cause by broken database connection especially at local server, when one forget to start XAMPP or WAMPP server.

Comment: I don't see a folder var. [Ner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057131/ner?tab=profile)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a "tmp" folder in your Magento installation directory? If not, make one and see if that helps!

EDIT: Failing that, check your upload_tmp_dir in php.ini - make sure it's set.

Comment: I added tmp folder, but that didn't solve it. Also I don't see php.ini file. Where it should be located? I see only this one php.ini.sample.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this problem appears when magento updated automatically.
I restored my back up and bingo it starts working properly.

Answer (score 1):

From your log file description, I see that you need to specify cache folder for your Magento site.

Navigate to **/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php**, find

```
'cache_dir' => null,
```

and change it to

```
'cache_dir' => tmp/,
```

Remember to create tmp folder in your root folder of Magento to make it work.

Reference source: https://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-fix-magento-500-internal-server-errors-in-magento-and-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

Rename **pub/local.xml.sample** into **local.xml** . then i will show you exactly error.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cache and your website will be work well.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it is cause by broken database connection especially at local server, when one forget to start XAMPP or WAMPP server,

**solution -1** :- Rename pub/local.xml.sample into local.xml or pub/local.xml into local.xml.sample if this is not work try solution 2

solution 2 :- [go to php.ini file and increase max_execution time and fresh install magento confirm issue resolved](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqJOohTRCgE&t=1s)

Answer (score 0):

A common solution is to upgrade magento setup by running this command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Otherwise just check `var/report/{error number}`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a problem like this and it turns out that I accidentally changed the permission of the var/cache folder. Just delete the cache folder so magento could automatically create the folder with the right permissions.

```
rm -rf root/var/cache
```

Answer (score -2):

When magento mode is default it showws such error 
Change magento mode to developer with

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

then check your error on your browser and resolve that