# Can't Login with Admin in Magento

Tags: magento, authentication, admin

I moving my Magento website to another hosting and everything is fine. But i cannot login!

I have Magento 1.7.0.2

I tried absolutely every solutions on the web, but I didn't succeed yet!

---

**Solution:** [There has been an error processing your request, Error log record number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473705/magento-admin-panel-errors)

Comment: Be more specific by what you tried and what happens when you try to login. Also show here if you have any errors in server error_log.

Comment: also check if this can help.. http://ka.lpe.sh/2011/06/05/magento-1-5-cant-login-to-admin-panel-after-fresh-install/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the secure and insecure url are correct in db

If they are correct remove all the subfolder of var for example: var/cache

Then refresh the cache in cache management

It would surely work after this :)

Comment: Ok, i get into Dashboard, BUT only there. When try to go in any other menu is Magento error happen.....

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia3GB.png When i clicked on link inside Admin Menu redirect me: http://mensattire.co.uk/index.php/admin/slideshow/index/key/b0ff0ebe53a01c859c122c577d676c2f/

Comment: You have some custom code in your header.phtml
That is throwing error
Can you post the code in your header.phtml so that I can check

Comment: seems like you have updated your magento via connect and its interrupted...

Check if var folder has 777 or 775 access

Comment: Thanks for advices, i find out solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473705/magento-admin-panel-errors

Answer (score 0):

Here's what fixed it for me. Got to your .htaccess file find

`##cookie-free domains`
`Header unset Cookie`
`Header unset Set-Cookie`

And comment them out

`##cookie-free domains` 
`#Header unset Cookie` 
`#Header unset Set-Cookie`

That should fix it.