# Magento: Can't log into admin

Tags: php, mysql, magento, authentication, admin

I have moved my Magento installation to a different host, and changed the domain name. I have also switched from using https to http.

For some reason, I can not log into the admin area. When I click on "log in", nothing happens - it just reloads the page.

If I click on "Forgot your password", it asks me to enter my email, but there the same thing happens - it just reloads the page, without doing anything.

I have tried changing the secure/unsecure base URL, deleting var/cache but nothing seems to work so far.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

**NOTE: Other similar questions do NOT apply. I have tried all the suggestions, which did not work. This is NOT a duplicate.**

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question.

Comment: Have upgraded your magento to 1.8.1 from prev versions ?

Comment: If you search before posting here you will get your answer......

Comment: Thanks for the replies. This was not an upgrade. Just a move. I did search before posting, and did not have any luck with the previous answers.

Comment: please provide with more details.like for eg did you moved the code grom localhost to live domain etc ?

Comment: @PradeepSanku Hi - no, this was moved from live server to live.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the secure and insecure `url` are correct in `db`

If they are correct remove all the **sub-folder** of var for example: `var/cache`

Then refresh the cache in cache management

hope this will works! you can also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473705/there-has-been-an-error-processing-your-request-error-log-record-number).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have manually changed secure/insecure URLs in the database. Deleted var/cache. Still no luck. :(

Comment: did you refresh the `cache` in **cache management**?

Comment: Hi - I can not log into admin. That's the main issue :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176195/cant-log-in-to-magento-admin

Comment: @FiascoLabs I did see that, and tried - did not work.